# How to format ListView Rows

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I have the following xml file for my CustomAdapter:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nullline"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application"
        android:textColor="#0099CC" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nullline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#0099CC"
        android:text="seas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstLine"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Secondline"
        android:textColor="#0099CC" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I tried to format this by adding `layout_above` but one of my TextViews are shown on top of the other.

What I want to display is

TEXTVIEW ONE

TEXTVIEW TWO

TEXTVIEW THREE

How can I display it like this if `layout_below` does not work?

Comment: *"among the other"*? Sorry, but I don't know what this means... Do you mean "besides" (as in side to side)? What Layout are you using as base?

Comment: Can you edit your question with full xml and possibly UI design you want, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like you want (if i have understood you....)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:padding="6dip">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="My Application"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nullline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine"
    android:textColor="#0099CC"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nullline"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Secondline"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />
```

layout_below works if you use it well :)

Answer (score 1):

`layout_below` does work. However, the easiest thing here would be to make it a `LinearLayout` with vertical `orientation`. But some things I see wrong here is

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nullline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#0099CC"
    android:text="seas" />
```

`height` is `fill_parent` and you have `alignParentRight` and `alignParentLeft` set to `true`. That seems like it would take up the whole screeen. Try something like

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="My Application"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nullline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#0099CC"
    android:text="seas" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nullLine"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Secondline"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />
```

I haven't had a chance to test it but something like that should get you started. It looked like you also had some recursive layouts such as telling `view1` to be left of `view2` and `view2` to be right of `view1`. It seems like it should do the same thing but it can cause recursive errors

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading the [LayoutParameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for the `RelativeLayout` if you haven't already.

The views are on top of each other because you're using the wrong property/properties for what you need to acquire. For example:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/firstLine"
```

should probably be:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/firstLine"
```

That's because `layout_alignBottom` *makes the bottom edge of this view match the bottom edge of the given anchor view ID*, while `layout_below` *positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID*.